# iOS contacts issue

Tags: contacts, iphone

I've got an odd thing going on with my contacts. In contacts I can only see about 6 names (I had loads) and all my SMS's are now showing numbers in the history when they used to be names, however if I send an SMS and start typing in a name, the number comes up (even though they are not showing in my contacts).

Any idea how to restore my contacts as they are in there, or in the ether somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Go to contacts in your iphone, click on group(It should be on top left of the screen).
select all the options which are there i.e.all icloud,all mail,all etc...

And then click done.

This generally happens when we store our contacts in a different place eg mail(normally my contacts are backed up @icloud).That option is not selected in the contact..

Hopefully this will resolve the issue..